# JQuery appending elements and acces to appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have a code where i appending to div some html over JQuery like

```
$("#divId").append("<div class='click' data-id='id'></div>");
```

and I want to acces by click appended div like this

```
$(".click").click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
alert(id);
});
```

but when I click, nothink happens, is there some solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery click event not working after append method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420558/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-append-method)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144892/jquery-dynamic-form-event-on-dynamic-field/32145552#32145552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event Delegation.

```
$("body").on('click', '.click', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   alert(id);
});
```

As the events are only bound for already existing elements on the page. but in your case you are dynamically appending the elements.

`body` can also be substituted to the closest ancestor that contains these elements.

```
$("#divId").on('click',
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpghcc56/)**

Comment: Is must be over body? or it can be divID?

Comment: It can be `#divId`  too in this case. The close the container the better